# RubyMine + Vagrant : Error Copying Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, rubymine

I'm currently evaluating RubyMine 7.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.8.5, and I'm trying to get my Ruby on Rails project up and running in the editor but after I try to bundle, I get "Error Copying Gems". Locally I use rbenv but this project uses Vagrant with Ruby 2.1.

I've gone into RubyMine Preferences -> Languages and Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems and set up a "Remote Interpreter" which looks like it is correctly pulling in my Vagrant / SSH information.

After I click OK, it looks like it correctly pulls down the gems, and copies them to the vendor/bundle folder, but then the IDE pops up an error message saying :

```
"Error Copying Gems - Unknown message with code 'Could not determine the type of file sftp://127.0.0.0.1:2222/......'"
```

or sometimes I'll get a more detailed error:

```
"Error Copying Gems - Could not copy sftp://127.0.0.1:2222/usr/bin/sudoedit to file://Users/my.username/Library/Caches/RubyMine70/ruby_stubs/....."
```

It feels like it is trying to copy them to a local cache folder on my Mac but failing for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar albeit different problem, maybe you are making the same mistake:

When setting up RubyMine to work with Vagrant, I am assuming you are adding a remote interpreter using the Vagrant dialogue. There it asks you to input the path to ruby executible. This is misleading, what you need is **the path to where the gems are installed**.

I'm also assuming you using RVM on your VM, as you indicate that you are not using rbenv on your VM.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by following the symlink steps found http://randycoulman.com/blog/2013/11/05/rubymine-and-vagrant/

Basically, RubyMine isn't trying to save things on your host machine. Its trying to save things to that particular path on your guest OS.  I worked around this issue by creating the `/Users/user_name/...` directory on my guest OS, and then symlinking the directory that has the projects to `/vagrant` (Again, on the guest OS)